# How to apply css to all child elements in Gtk3-css?

Tags: css, css-selectors, gtk3

### Issue with nested components:

I am trying to apply a background to GtkComboBoxText.

I am aquiring the context of the widget and applying CSS to it:

```
 * { background: red }
```

This does not change the color of GtkComboBoxText. But it works for GtkButton and GtkLabel.

Looking at GtkInspector, it seems that GtkComboBoxText has nested controls like GtkToggleButton and GtkEntry and the CSS above doesn't get applied to them. 
If I manually traverse all the nested components via gtk_container_forall(..) and pick out the selected components, then background coloring works. But I can't seem to find a way to apply the CSS once to GtkComboBoxText and let it perculate down to all the children?

Is this possible?

### Test Snippet

A test snippet can be found in repo:
https://github.com/LeoUfimtsev/LeoGtk3/tree/3_GtkCombo_background

To run:

```
  git clone https://github.com/LeoUfimtsev/LeoGtk3.git
  make
  ./main
```

### Things tried:

```
 * {background:red}
 * {background-color:red} //no impact

 GtkComboBoxText * { background: red}
 GtkComboBoxText * { background-color: red}
```

### Do note please:

If I run the snippet, then open CSS inspector, then apply:

```
 * {background: red}
```

To each individual sub-widget:

GtkComboBoxText
  - GtkToggleButton  <<
  - GtkTreeMenu <<

then background coloring works.

[image]

### Edit - use style classes?

It seems that one way is to add a style class to a widget and then select it from the global css. An example is here:
https://github.com/LeoUfimtsev/LeoGtk3/blob/057884368bf38a626dbaac5c575c15a5e1c93f2f/main.c#L35

However, this is not practical if you are implementing a graphics library on top of GTK as you'd have 1000's of classes to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
GtkComboBoxText * {
  background-color: red;
}
```

If the above css is not supported by GTK+, it does support `GtkBin * {/* styles here */}` which applies a style to all children of the `GtkBin` so you could put your `GtkComboBoxText` inside a `GtkBin` element (which might also need `GtkComboBox` first in the hierarchy so the hierarchy is `GtkBin > GtkComboBox GtkComboBoxText`).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have tried, but this did not work. I don't think it's an issue with the snippet as I tried it in GtkInspector to apply directly to GtkComboBoxText with no luck.

Comment: Please note, I added substantial amount of info to question.

Comment: Ok I'm not sure i understand your question. Do you want to apply the background color to all child elements of GtkComboBoxText?

Comment: Yes, to all child elements. I fixed the title.

Comment: I read your updated on the question. GtkBin doesn't have any method to intiate it. How would I go about putting GtkComboBoxText into GtkBin?

Comment: This snippet actually works if applied to the global CSS sheet, but not when local to a provider.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation 3.20+](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/class.ToggleButton.html#css-nodes) I found this working:

```
button.toggle {
  background: red;
}

button.toggle:checked {
  background: blue;
}
```

background-color is not working.